# Wrap first level of "li" tags into one div using Jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, tags, html-lists

Consider we have a multi-level html list that looks like this:

```html
<ul class="catalog">
  <li>
    <ul>
      <li>
        <ul>
          <li>subcat subcat 1</li>
          <li>subcat subcat 2</li>
          <li>subcat subcat 3</li>
        </ul>
      </li>
      <li>subcat 2</li>
      <li>subcat 3</li>
    </ul>
  </li>
  <li>
    <ul>
      <li>subcat 4</li>
      <li>subcat 5</li>
      <li>subcat 6</li>
    </ul>
  </li>

</ul>
```

I need to wrap into one div only `<li>` tags (hamed "header 1", "header 2"... and all its children) which belong to first level of the list.

The result should be:

```html
<ul class="catalog">
  <div class="myWrapper">
    <!-- Added by JQuery -->
    <li>
      <ul>
        <li>
          <ul>
            <li>subcat subcat 1</li>
            <li>subcat subcat 2</li>
            <li>subcat subcat 3</li>
          </ul>
        </li>
        <li>subcat 2</li>
        <li>subcat 3</li>
      </ul>
    </li>
    <li>
      <ul>
        <li>subcat 4</li>
        <li>subcat 5</li>
        <li>subcat 6</li>
      </ul>
    </li>

  </div>
  <!-- Added by JQuery -->

</ul>
```

I tried `wrap()` function but it did not work as expected

Any ideas how to do this job?

Comment: Well you can do this...but that's not valid HTML, what is your ultimate goal?

Comment: and your `<ul>`'s should be inside the `<li>` like so: `<li>header1 <ul> ...many li tags ...</ul></li><li>header2</li>`

Comment: Nick Craver: my first post at stackoverflow, sorry
fixed

Comment: @volocuga - I was referring to the markup :) You can't have a `<div>` in a `<ul>`, same for a `<ul>` in a `<ul>`, they need to be within a child `<li>`

Comment: Nick Craver: you're right,edited

Comment: grahamparks: the solution you provided clear and simple, thanks!
I played with it and dicided to move my wrapper one level deeper

I modified your code a little bit: 
$('.catalog ul > li').wrapAll('<div class="wrapper"></div>');

It still works but I see that all li's under wrapper are empty now

Any advices? Thanks!

Comment: @volocuga - I added a solution below for valid html...the invalid HTML is probably what's causing your rendering issues, the basics are invalid = unpredictable.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, let's start with valid HTML, like this:

```
<ul class="catalog">
   <li>header 1
      <ul>
        <li>subcat 1
            <ul>
               <li>subcat subcat 1</li>
               <li>subcat subcat 2</li>
               <li>subcat subcat 3</li>
            </ul>
        </li>
        <li>subcat 2</li>
        <li>subcat 3</li>
      </ul>
   </li>
   <li>header 2
      <ul>
        <li>subcat 4</li>
        <li>subcat 5</li>
        <li>subcat 6</li>
      </ul>
    </li>
</ul>​
```

Then you cap wrap them using [`.wrapAll()`](http://api.jquery.com/wrapAll/), like this:

```
$(".catalog > li").wrapAll("<li><div class='something'><ul></ul></div></li>");​
```

This results in valid HTML, like this:

```
<ul class="catalog">
  <li>
    <div class="something">
      <ul>
        <li>header 1
          <ul>
            <li>subcat 1
                <ul>
                   <li>subcat subcat 1</li>
                   <li>subcat subcat 2</li>
                   <li>subcat subcat 3</li>
                </ul>
            </li>
            <li>subcat 2</li>
            <li>subcat 3</li>
          </ul>
        </li><li>header 2
          <ul>
            <li>subcat 4</li>
            <li>subcat 5</li>
            <li>subcat 6</li>
          </ul>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </li>  
</ul>
```

[You can test it out here](http://jsfiddle.net/VrcSe/), though you can probably get the *effect* you want with styling on the original `<ul>`, `display: block` for example.

Answer (score 3):

`$('.catalog > li').wrapAll('<div class="wrapper"></div>');`

But you're both starting and ending with seriously invalid HTML, so you should probably fix that then ask this question again.